# Batch script to create a date time folder

Tags: date, batch-file, timestamp

I used the following to create a folder with a date and timestamp

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a-%%b)

set mydir="%mydate%-%mytime%"

mkdir %mydir%
```

Instead of created a folder named 2020-5-19-11-30 AM, I get one folder named 2020-5-19 and another folder called AM.

Any idea? I just want to run a batch file that will create a date and time including am or pm for a folder.

Comment: Would you mind trying to print the result of `date /t` and `time /t`? The values are different for different machines.

Comment: `date` and `time` formats depend on your settings (you can change them in the control panel or through the registry) You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-date-time-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format/19799236#19799236)

Comment: Are you saying you get two folders next to each other, although there is a single `mkdir` command? Well, I can't reproduce that...

Comment: There are already two variables called `%date` and `%time%` that are built in. Put quotes around the `%mydir%` in the `mkdir "%mydir%"`. There might be a delimiter in the `%mydir%` variable

Comment: Like @npocmaka said, `date` and `time` formats are different depending on the computer, however for me, if I remove the quotes in teh definition of `%mydir%` so it is defined like `set mydir=%mydate%-%mytime%` and then `mkdir "%mydir%"` it worked fine. `%date%` and `%time%` are already environment automatic variables so your `for` loop is redundant unless you want a different format than the actual `%date%` and `%time%` commands.